# iOS6 barcode reader, using ZBarSDK, should I change?

Tags: xcode, ios6

Im using the ZBarSDK barcode reader in my app, but it is not compiled to run on arm7s.

Im wondering if I should rather use a different library for my barcode scanning.

Im experiencing some problems with ZBarSDK, like problems with reading barcodes on some devices.

Comment: Why don't you compile your ZBarSDK to work with arm7 as well?  You might have a happier experience.  Or is that your question?

Comment: If I remember correctly (I ultimately didn't use it due to the licensing requirements), ZBarSDK comes as a binary. You can download the source, of course, but the kit wasn't really geared towards it. He might not be aware the source option exists.

Comment: Well it works with arm7, but not arm7s, and I do not know what impact it has on the app that I remove arm7s as a valid architecture. I do not have any experience in compiling other peoples libraries. Im kinda asking if someone have tried or would recommend a different library, or if I have chosen the best 1 by using ZBarSDK.

Comment: Can you remember what part of the licensing requirements made you not choose it.

Comment: Check out my answer on a related SO post that solved this issue for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12504867/1106878

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up paying for the SD toolkit barcode scanner, since I did not like the ZBar license agreement.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the "armv7s" on ZBarSDK, this will work :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the beta version (1.3.1), which is working fine with optimized arm7 arch.