# Zbar SDK is not working well in iOS6

Tags: iphone, ios6, zbar-sdk

I'm implementing an application in which I want to scan QR code. For this I have used Zbar SDK and it's scanning QR code correctly. But the problem is that, while scanning, unless and until I take a look of anything else than QR code,the QR code is not getting captured. Same application is working on iOS 5. But giving this problem on iOS 6.

Can anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: I have solve this issue by following steps from http://stackoverflow.com/a/12561312/1411780

Answer (score 1):

> To solved the problem follow the steps:

**1.Go to the ZBar homepage and navigate to the mercurial repository [*Direct Link*](http://zbar.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/zbar)**

**2.    Download the zbar repository as zip.**

**3.    Unzip the file and navigate to the subfolder named “iphone”.**

**4.    Open the XCode project.**

**5.    Delete the “Examples” folder (the folder caused a build error on my machine).**

**6.    Hit “CMD + B” and build the source.**

**7.    Find your new libzbar.a file. (User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/zbar…)**

**8.    Replace the old libzbar.a file in your project with the new one.**

**9.    Hit “CMD + R” and you are good to go.**