# ZBar SDK is not working in xcode 7

Tags: zbar-sdk

I have added the `ZBar` SDK in my project and the required frameworks as in the  SDK docs. But I am getting the following error:

> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

I am unable to solve it, does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Zbar SDK is not working in iOS6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506671/zbar-sdk-is-not-working-in-ios6)

Comment: i am not getting [armv7s] error. It is just one line 'clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)'.